# Passing query data between classes using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using Visual Studio 2012 C#, and I am attempting to pass some data between classes.  So basically, I have two classes.  One class is used to query the data, and the other class is used to just display the data(essentially the UI).

I am guessing I need to put it in some sort of data container and pass it.  However, I am currently a student, and cannot figure out what the best way to do this.

```
public List<string> GetDatabyID(int ID)
{
    var context = new Site.EFModel.SiteDBEntities();
    var query = context.db.Where(x => x.ID == ID).Select(x => new {x.ID, x.Name});
    List<string> dataContainer = query.ToList();

    return dataContainer;
}
```

In the UI, I would like to map this data to a GridView to output it.  My code is clearly wrong.  I obviously cannot return it as a List when dataContainer is going to contain an int and string.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks ahead.

Comment: if you are using x.id and x.name why not create a dictionary with X.ID key and x.name value or alternative it to craete a class with variables id and name

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an `Anonymous Object` from the results of your database call. The Linq method `Select`:

```
Select(x => new {x.ID, x.Name});
```

projects the results into a new object of your choice, in this case an anonymous object. This should be set to create and return a list of one of your EF entities.

```
var query = context.db.Where(x => x.ID == ID).Select(
    x => new MyEntity {ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name});
List<MyEntity> dataContainer = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Just managed to get it all to work this morning.  Was probably a simple issue, but I learned a lot.  Thank you!